# Is it possible to attach delegate to FBSDKShareDialog presented by FBSDKShareButton?

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

From the Facebook documentation I know that FBSDKShareButton uses FBSDKShareDialog under the hood. It's easy to attach a delegate to the dialog, but how attach a delegate to the dialog which is presented via button in different way than this?

```
if let dialog = shareButton.value(forKey: "_dialog") as? FBSDKShareDialog{
    dialog.delegate = aDelegate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"_dialog"` is a private property. Your code is the best way to access it.